# 400 bad request from jersey when upload a file

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, file-upload, jersey

I'm using Jersey to upload a file.
This is the rest:

```
@Path("/MyUpload")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String MyUpload(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                           @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInfo)    {


// here I’m handling the input stream
…
return “Ok”;
}
```

When I send a file with size more than 10KB I get 400 bad request for this method.

Any ideas?

I'm running my app on tomcat7 with linux red hat 6.2.

Thanks..

Comment: Have you found the solution in the past 2 years???

Comment: Yes, I've added the jersey-multipart-config.properties to classes folder with bufferThreshold=1024

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are fetching both the request `multipart` params using the same name `file`. You need to distinguish the two parts using different names for `multipart` params.

Comment: This does not explain the 10KB limit of files which actually can be uploaded if they are smaller.

Comment: I'm (very) late, but wanted to point out that the name `file` *must* be equal: the difference is in the parameter type, so that `fileInfo` can correctly receive the metadata associated with the file in `uploadedInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is: change the buggy Jersey libs from version 1.13 (or lower) to the latest version. 1.17 and 1.19 worked for me.